# RD Gateway traffic and RD Connection Brokers

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019, remote-desktop-gateway

So we currently had to emergency deploy a RDS server. The setup is running on Windows 2019 Server and all is fine at this stage. I have one RD Session Host server and the RD Licensing Server and RD Web Access Server is on another separate server.
We can handle easily 40-50 concurrent session but what to up this a little bit. So it is clear how to add another RD Session Host Server and now I would need another server as a RD Gateway server. However, I cannot get an understanding from the Microsoft Technet documentation on the following:

- Is it necessary to also deploy a RD Connection Broker, irrespective if high availability is needed (solution is running on VMware), if I want to make use of more than one RD Session Host Server?
- In terms of RDP traffic - does the RD Gateway server handle the RDP traffic to the RD Session hosts end to end? I would assume only allowing the RD Gateway server RDP access via the firewall is sufficient as the connections to the other RD Session Hosts goes back to the RD Gateway Server?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-roles "If a session disconnects, RD Connection Broker will reconnect the user to the correct RD Session Host server and their interrupted session"

Comment: So actually I only need to add a RD Connection Broker server once I add a second RD Session Host server? The RD Gateway server is not required to make sure my connections are spread to the RD Session Host servers?

Comment: The gateway provides a central acess point, and can also provide centralized access control. It does not load balance connections.